# Staying in the same page without refreshing it after adding to database

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have PHP web page where I need to insert some information to my database. When insert is done, it refresh the same page. But I've been told that this process is not practical because you are loading all `HTML`, `CSS`, and `JS` of your page every time. And I should you `AJAX` to do that.

I search for it, and tried this code:

```
$("#insert").click(function(){
 //get the form values
 var selectType = $('#selectW').val();
 var selectcom = $('#select_at').val();
 var pay = $('#pay').val();     
 var facture = $('#facture').val();     
 var selectcur = $('#select').val(); 

 //make the postdata
 //var postData = 'username='+username+'&name='+name+'&brand='+brand;

 //call your input.php script in the background, when it returns it will call the success function if the request was successful or the error one if there was an issue (like a 404, 500 or any other error status)

     $.ajax({
        url : "insert.php",
        type: "POST",
        data : postData,
        success: function(data,status, xhr)
        {
            //if success then just output the text to the status div then clear the form inputs to prepare for new data
            $("#section2").html(data);
            $('#pay').val('');
            $('#selectcur').val('');
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, status, errorThrown)
        {
            //if fail show error and server status
            $("#section2").html('there was an error ' + errorThrown + ' with status ' + textStatus);
        }
    });// JavaScript Document
```

And here is my `PHP-PDO` code where I removed the `header` lines and replaced them with `echo("something")`:

```
if(isset($_POST['insert'])){
    $selectOpt1 = $_POST['currency'];
    if($selectOpt1=="9"){
        $type = $_POST['type'];
        $provider = $_POST['alfa_touch'];
        $pay = $_POST['pay'];
        $facture = $_POST['facture'];
        try{
            $query = "INSERT INTO sales
            (type, provider, pay, facture, date_now, time_now) 
            VALUES
            (:type, :provider, :pay, :facture, :date, now())";
            $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
            $stmt->bindValue(":type", $type);
            $stmt->bindValue(":provider", $provider);
            $stmt->bindValue(":pay", $pay);  
            $stmt->bindValue(":facture", $facture);
            $stmt->bindValue(":date", date("y-m-d"));
            $count = $stmt->execute();
            //header("location: home.php");
            echo ("Done");
        }
        catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
            //header("location: ../pages/insert_false.php?id=".$projid);
            print_r($conn->errorInfo());

        }


    }
}
```

Now, when I click on insert button, the data are added correctly to MySQL database, but, the app stay in insert.php and echo `Done`. What I need is to stay in the same page. Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT**

```
$("#insert").click(function(){
 //get the form values
 var selectType = $('#selectW').val();
 var selectcom = $('#select_at').val();
 var pay = $('#pay').val();     
 var facture = $('#facture').val();     
 var selectcur = $('#select').val(); 

 //make the postdata
 var postData = 'username='+username+'&name='+name+'&brand='+brand;

 //call your input.php script in the background, when it returns it will call the success function if the request was successful or the error one if there was an issue (like a 404, 500 or any other error status)

 $.ajax({
    url : "insert.php",
    type: "POST",
    data : postData,
    success: function(data,status, xhr)
    {
        //if success then just output the text to the status div then clear the form inputs to prepare for new data
        $("#section2").html(data);
        $('#pay').val('');
        $('#selectcur').val('');
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, status, errorThrown)
    {
        //if fail show error and server status
        $("#section2").html('there was an error ' + errorThrown + ' with status ' + textStatus);
    }

});
return false;
});// JavaScript Document
```

Still the same problem. And here is my HTML form:

```
<form name="insertForm" action="insert.php" method="post">

    <tr>
        <td align="center">
          <select id="selectW" name="type">
            <option value="Choose">Choose</option>
            <option value="Dollars">Dollars</option>
            <option value="D & D">D & D</option>
            <option value="Cards">Cards</option>
            <option value="Phones">Phones</option>
            <option value="Acc">Acc</option>
            <option value="Bills">Bills</option>
          </select>
          <!--<select>
          <?php foreach($result5 as $rows){ ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $rows['item_name'] ?>"><?php echo $rows['item_name'] ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
          </select>-->
          </td>
        <td align="center"><select id="select_at" name="alfa_touch">
            <option value="Undefined">Not Required</option>
            <option value="Alfa">Alfa</option>
            <option value="Touch">Touch</option></select></td>
        <td align="center"><input type="text" id="pay" name="pay"/></td>
        <td align="center"><input type="text" id="facture" name="facture" placeholder="في حال دفع الفواتير عبر omt"/></td>
        <td align="center"><select id="select" name="currency">
            <option value="9">LBP</option>
            <option value="10">Dollars</option>
            </select></td>

        <td align="center"><input type="submit" id="insert" name="insert" value="insert" />

      </td>

      </tr>
      </form>
```

Comment: Which file is `insert.php`, and how does the app "stay" there? Do you mean when you click the button, it redirects to insert.php?

Comment: Yes, data added successfully into db and we stay in insert.php that contain only php code and echo "Done". AJAX should let me stay in the page where my web form is not to stay in insert.php

Comment: Have you checked what are you sending using browser console? Because I see var postData is not set in jQuery function. Also you are not sending "insert" in post data. So the code doesn't enters if statement

Comment: Do you have an `action` attribute in your form? If you do have, include `return false;` at the end of your javascript function.

Comment: yes I have an action for the form

Comment: see my edit, still the same problem

Comment: Still testing, data are added but still redirecting and echoing

Comment: You can use pjax. For an example see http://pjax.herokuapp.com/ and the plugin: https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax.

Comment: @meysam I just need to do it with AJAX, I don't know about PJAX, it may be slightly different, but solving this problem with AJAX is recommended

Comment: I know. Just i remove my answer and comment a solution ;). Also pjax is not a different thing, it's a solution based on jquery and its ajax method, with more functions.

Answer (score 0):

Add preventDefault to your javascript function

```
    Function(e){

    e.preventDefault()

    ...

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34586658/no-added-datainto-database-and-nt-shown-in-table-append-using-ajax-and-php

Answer (score 0):

In your `HTML` file you have `action = 'insert.php'` in `<form>` tag and you are also calling a function on `button` `click` having `id` `insert`.

Both are doing the same thing - sending values from `HTML` page to `insert.php`. In case `<form>`, page gets refreshed so go for `ajax`.
Keep the script for `click` event.

1. Remove `action="insert.php"` and `method="post"` from `<form>` tag.
2. Change `type = "button"` in `<button>` tag.

Hope this will help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34586658/no-added-datainto-database-and-nt-shown-in-table-append-using-ajax-and-php