# Unknown error using AJAX to stay in the same page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Following [this previous link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34563800/staying-in-the-same-page-without-refreshing-it-after-adding-to-database), I tried a new AJAX code, but still getting the same result (Data is inserted correctly, but can't stay in the same page).

```
$(function(){
    $("#form1").on("submit", function(e){
        $.ajax({
          url: 'insert.php',
          type: 'post',
          data: $('#form1').serialize(),
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(data) {
              alert($('#form1').serialize());
         });
         e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

[image]

The form has an `id="form1"` and submit button inside this form is `id="insert"`.

Any help is appreciated, need to fix this today.

Comment: likely have errors thrown in console preventing code from working properly

Comment: no, the console is empty, no errors shown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `success` function should be closed before closing AJAX function. You forgot to add a closing `}`:

```
$(function(){
  $("#form1").on("submit", function(e){
    $.ajax({
      url: 'insert.php',
      type: 'post',
      data: $('#form1').serialize(),
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        alert($('#form1').serialize() + "&insert=yes"); // add this
      } //<--------------------------------------- You missed this
    });
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

You are sending the `insert` key as a parameter to post, but it doesn't work because you are not adding it while sending to AJAX. So add that and it works.