# No added datainto database, and not shown in table append using AJAX and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am still in the same problem [in this link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34563800/staying-in-the-same-page-without-refreshing-it-after-adding-to-database/34586455). So, I used the `append` method. And here is the `AJAX` code:

```
<script>
function addFunction()
{
    var selectW = $('#insert_new').val();
    var selectW = $('#selectW').val();
    var select_at = $('#select_at').val();
    var pay = $('#pay').val();
    var facture = $('#facture').val();
    var select_opt = $('#select_opt').val();

    if(pay!="")
    {
        $.ajax({
            data: {'text': insert_new, 'text': selectW, 'text': select_at, 'text': pay, 'text': facture, 'text': select_opt},
            type: "post",
            url: "insert.php",
            success: function(response){
              if(response=="success")
              {
                $('#incident_table').append('<tr><td>'+selectW+'</td><td>'+select_at+'</td><td>'+pay+'</td><td>'+facture+'</td><td>'+select_opt+'</td></tr>');
                $('#selectW').val('');
                $('#select_at').val('');
                $('#pay').val('');
                $('#facture').val('');
                $('#select_opt').val('');
              }
              else
              {
                alert("No data added");
              }
            },
            error: function(){
                alert('error; ' + eval(error));
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Specify a value of payment please!!");
    }
}
</script>
```

And here is the form where I removed `action=insert.php` and `method=post` and transformed the button `type=submit` into `button` in my `<form>`. So the form is:

```
    <form name="insertForm" id="form1">
<input type="hidden" name="insert" value="true">
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
          <select id="selectW" name="type">
            <option value="لم يتم التحديد">اختر النوع</option>
            <option value="دولارات">دولارات</option>
            <option value="أيام + دولارات">أيام + دولارات</option>
            <option value="بطاقات">بطاقات</option>
            <option value="هواتف">هواتف</option>
            <option value="اكسسوارات">اكسسوارات</option>
            <option value="تسديد فواتير">تسديد فواتير</option>
          </select>
          <!--<select>
          <?php foreach($result5 as $rows){ ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $rows['item_name'] ?>"><?php echo $rows['item_name'] ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
          </select>-->
          </td>
        <td align="center"><select id="select_at" name="alfa_touch">
            <option value="غير محدد">Not Required</option>
            <option value="Alfa">Alfa</option>
            <option value="Touch">Touch</option></select></td>
        <td align="center"><input type="text" id="pay" name="pay"/></td>
        <td align="center"><input type="text" id="facture" name="facture" placeholder="في حال دفع الفواتير عبر omt"/></td>
        <td align="center"><select id="select_opt" name="currency">
            <option value="9">ليرة</option>
            <option value="10">دولار</option>
            </select></td>

        <td align="center"><input type="button" id="insert_new" onClick="addFunction()" name="insert_new" value="اضافة" />

      </td>

      </tr>
      </form>
```

Here is my `insert.php` file, where I have a long codes for different submit buttons in my project, but I will post only the code used for this AJAX function:

```
    $selectOpt1="";
    if(isset($_REQUEST['insert_new'])){

error_reporting(E_ALL); 
require_once ('../include/global.php');
$selectOpt1 = $_REQUEST['select_opt'];
    if($selectOpt1=="9"){
        $type = $_REQUEST['selectW'];
        $provider = $_REQUEST['select_at'];
        $pay = $_REQUEST['pay'];
        $facture = $_REQUEST['facture'];
        try{
            $query = "INSERT INTO sales
            (type, provider, pay, facture, date_now, time_now) 
            VALUES
            (:type, :provider, :pay, :facture, :date, now())";
            $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
            $stmt->bindValue(":type", $type);
            $stmt->bindValue(":provider", $provider);
            $stmt->bindValue(":pay", $pay);  
            $stmt->bindValue(":facture", $facture);
            $stmt->bindValue(":date", date("y-m-d"));
            $count = $stmt->execute();
            //header("location: home.php");
            echo "success";
            //$last_id = $conn->lastInsertId();
            //echo $last_id;
        }
        catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
            //header("location: ../pages/insert_false.php?id=".$projid);
            print_r($conn->errorInfo());

        }


    }

    if($selectOpt1=="10"){
        $type = $_REQUEST['type'];
        $provider = $_REQUEST['alfa_touch'];
        $payL = $_REQUEST['pay'];
        $pay = $payL*1500;
        $facture = $_REQUEST['facture'];
        try{
            $query = "INSERT INTO sales
            (type, provider, pay, facture, date_now, time_now) 
            VALUES
            (:type, :provider, :pay, :facture, :date, now())";
            $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
            $stmt->bindValue(":type", $type);
            $stmt->bindValue(":provider", $provider);
            $stmt->bindValue(":pay", $pay);  
            $stmt->bindValue(":facture", $facture);
            $stmt->bindValue(":date", date("y-m-d"));
            $count = $stmt->execute();
            echo "success";
            //header("location: home.php");

        }
        catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
            //header("location: ../pages/insert_false.php?id=".$projid);
            print_r($conn->errorInfo());

        }


    }
    }
```

In console network I have those values:

[image]

And no errors in the console. And I kept seeing the alert: No data added.

**EDIT**
I have gotten this error message: Undefined select_opt in insert_buy.php (I changed the file from insert.php into insert_buy.php):

[image]

Comment: You need to properly close your <option> tags and their values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your data in ajax to this

```
data: {'insert_new': 'insert_new', 'selectW': selectW, 'select_at': select_at, 'pay': pay, 'facture': facture, 'select_opt': select_opt},
```

You are not getting any value because your data variable does't match with the $_request[] variables

Comment: And also you are not sending value for `alfa_touch` and `type`

Comment: Okay, data added correctly, but the table didn't append, and I refreshed the page with F5 to see the new row

Comment: the error alert me: No data added, But when I refresh the page, I see the new row added

Comment: currently I am on skype

Comment: I got your error after
`$count = $stmt->execute();`
This line add
`echo 'success';`

On both!

Comment: the table is not updated because your are not returning any response from your insert.php file

Comment: so I add echo "success" to my php file ?

Comment: nope, still the same, nothing is shown until I refresh the page

Comment: Okay, wait, it works only when selectOpt==9, but when I change it to selectOpt==10, it won't refresh the table

Comment: add the same line of code in selectOpt==10 too so it will work in both

Comment: are you sending type and alfatouch in your  query

Comment: Yes it works, it is inserted to database when selectOpt=10but I need ro refresh to see it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99677/discussion-between-ahmed-khan-and-androidnation).

Answer (score 0):

[1] Why are you catching `value` of a `button`

```
var selectW = $('#insert_new').val();
```

I think there is no need for that.

[2] Add this before `ajax` call

```
dataString = 'selectW='+ selectW + '&select_at='+ select_at + '&pay='+ pay+ '&facture='+facture+ '&select_opt='+ select_opt;
```

[3] In `ajax` call set `data' as

```
data: dataString,
```

instead of

```
 data: {'text': insert_new, 'text': selectW, 'text': select_at, 'text': pay, 'text': facture, 'text': select_opt},
```

[4] Why are you catching `response`, you are not sending any `string` back from `insert_buy.php`

```
          if(response=="success")
          {
```

as you are not getting `return value` as `"success"`, `else` part is getting executed and getting `alert` message as "No data added".

Comment: I corrected them, and I removed the condition of ISSET(submit)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34589853/sum-of-rows-is-not-update-when-running-ajac-code-until-f5-refresh

Answer (score 0):

please correct your json data which you are sending to server

```
 data: {'insert_new': 1, 'selectW': selectW, 'select_at': select_at, 'pay': pay, 'facture': facture, 'select_opt': select_opt},
```

and in php add a die

```
 if(isset($_REQUEST['insert_new'])){
     // your code

    die(); // just before closing the if to make sure you are not echoing anything more;
 }
```