# sum of rows is not updated when running AJAX code until F5 refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Following [this link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34586658/no-added-datainto-database-and-not-shown-in-table-append-using-ajax-and-php/34588439) about sending data into MySQL using AJAX, I have this output:

[image]

What I want, is to see the row with the curent rows shown in the div and not at the bottom. And how to refresh the sum, and not wait to refresh the page ?

Here is the final AJAX code:

```
function addFunction()
{
    var selectW = $('#insert_new').val();
    var selectW = $('#selectW').val();
    var select_at = $('#select_at').val();
    var pay = $('#pay').val();
    var facture = $('#facture').val();
    var select_opt = $('#select_opt').val();
    if(pay!="")
    {
        $.ajax({
            data: {'selectW': selectW, 'select_at': select_at, 'pay': pay, 'facture': facture, 'select_opt': select_opt},
            type: "post",
            url: "insert_buy.php",
            success: function(response){
                  if(response=="success")
                  {
                    $('#incident_table').append('<tr><td height="30" align="center">' + selectW + '</td><td align="center">' + select_at + '</td> <td align="center" dir="ltr">' + pay + '</td> <td align="center">' + facture + '</td> <td align="center"><form action="delete.php" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="rowid" value="" /><input class="imgClass_dell" type="submit" onclick="return confirm(\'هل أنت متأكد؟\')" name="delete_sales" value="" /></form></td></tr>');
                    alert(data);
                    $('#selectW').val('');
                    $('#select_at').val('');
                    $('#pay').val('');
                    $('#facture').val('');
                    $('#select_opt').val('');
                  }
                  else
                  {
                    alert("No Data added");

                  }
            },
            error: function(){
                //alert('error; ' + eval(error));
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        alert("All Fields Are Required!!");
    }

}
```

And here is where PHP calculate the sum:

```
      </tr>
      </form>   
      <?php
        $sum = 0;
        $selectAll = "SELECT * FROM sales WHERE date_now = :date ORDER BY date_now DESC, time_now DESC";
        $stmtAll=$conn->prepare($selectAll);
        $stmtAll->bindValue(':date', date("y-m-d"));
        $execAll=$stmtAll->execute();
        $result=$stmtAll->fetchAll();
      ?>
      <?php foreach($result as $rows){
          $sum = $sum + $rows['pay'];
          //var_Dump($rows) ?>
    <tr>
      <td height="30" align="center"><?php echo $rows['type'] ?></td>
      <td align="center"><?php echo $rows['provider'] ?></td>
      <td align="center" dir="ltr"><?php echo (number_format($rows['pay'], 0, ',', ' ')). ' L.L'?></td>
      <td align="center"><?php echo $rows['facture'] ?></td>
      <td align="center"><form action='delete.php' method="post">
          <input type="hidden" name="rowid" value="<?php echo $rows['id'] ?>" />
          <input class="imgClass_dell" type="submit" onclick="return confirm('هل أنت متأكد؟')" name="delete_sales" value="" />
        </form></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    <tr>
    <th colspan="4" align="center" bgcolor="#666666">المجموع</th>
    <td dir="ltr" bgcolor="#666666" align="center"><?php
        echo ($sum = number_format($sum, 0, ',', ' ')). ' L.L';
      ?></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
</div>
```

I hope I can get some help.

Comment: Show us the `insert_buy.php` code as well as that is what you are running in the AJAX call

Comment: You append a new row to your table using javascript, but you do not do anything to add this new value to your running total.

Comment: Find current row `index` and append `tr` like `$('#incident_table > tr').eq(i-1).after(html);` here `i` is your finded row index.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi `$('#incident_table tr:last').before(html);` would do the same.

Comment: @ImClarky should that not be `$('#incident_table tr:last').before(html)` so that the total line remains at the end of the table and the new row gets added just before the totals row

Comment: @RiggsFolly ah yes... forgot about the total row.

Comment: Then all you need to do is give the cell containing the running total an `id` eg `<td dir="ltr" bgcolor="#666666" align="center" id="total_cell">` then you can add `$('#pay').val('')` to it in the `.success` function. After removing the number part from the `L.L` and converting it to a number, then placing it back into that cell

Comment: @RiggsFolly how to do it ? Can you write an answer for it ?

Comment: Yup, but thats your job now you know what is required

Comment: at least give me some more hints, I barely know JavaScript, you want me to write An AJAX. Or at least a link please

Comment: Start here - http://www.amazon.com/Applied-jQuery-Develop-Jay-Blanchard/dp/0321772563

Answer (score 0):

you can try with this

You'll need a getTable.php page that displays your table, and nothing else: no headers, footers, etc.

PHP (getTable.php) - this can be any server side code (asp, html, etc..)

```
<?php
    echo '<table><tr><td>TEST</td></tr></table>';
?>
```

Then, in your JS, you can easily refresh the table by using the load() method:

HTML

```
<div id="tableHolder"></div>
```

js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      refreshTable();
    });

    function refreshTable(){
        $('#tableHolder').load('getTable.php', function(){
           setTimeout(refreshTable, 5000);
        });
    }
</script>
```

try and good luck i prefer work with jqgrid

Comment: well, I have gotten a wierd result, where the page home.php is above getTable.php